# How to add image link in a form using this encrypt code?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, encryption

How can this code supposed to do converting an image here? how can i define image from folder which is there in bin folder **"ch/1.jpg"** Can any one help me to solve this?
i have 20 pictures and 20 forms...

```
private static byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageToConvert, 
ImageFormat formatOfImage) 
{ 
byte[] Ret; 

try 
{ 

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
{ 
imageToConvert.Save(ms,formatOfImage); 
Ret = ms.ToArray(); 
} 
} 
catch (Exception) { throw;} 

return Ret; 
} 


//When you are ready to convert the byte array back 
//to an image, you can include the following code 
//in your method. 

System.Drawing.Image newImage; 


using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(myByteArray,0,myByteArray.Length)) 
{ 

ms.Write(myByteArray,0,myByteArray.Length); 

newImage = Image.FromStream(ms,true); 

// work with image here. 

// You'll need to keep the MemoryStream open for 
// as long as you want to work with your new image. 

}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but I didn't understand the question at all.. No clue what the ask is..

Comment: I'm asking that how can I add a image in this and how can i Show image in form?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an image from a file, just use:

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("C:\mypath\myimage.png");  //load the file as image
pictureBox1.Image = img;  //use the image how you like
```

You do not need to go through the process of converting the image information into a `Byte[]` unless you mean to store it somewhere, such as in a database.

Comment: I've so much images about 400 images and 400 forms, can i bind 400 images in one form with different buttons?

Comment: Sure.  Why would you want to?  Why are these 400 images not resources compiled into your project?

Comment: the application crashes if i add all into resources...!